# Solve the differential equation $2(x+y)\sin y dx + (2(x+y)\sin y + \cos y)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck in a rut. If we divide by $\cos y$, we get

$$2(x+y)\tan y dx + (2(x+y)\tan y + 1)dy=0$$

Using the substitution $x+y = u$

$$\frac{dx}{du}= 2u \tan (u-x) + 1$$

But I don't know how to proceed. Is there any shortcut with these kinds of  differentials? Or do they boil down to algebraic manipulation + trig identities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making $x(y)=u(y)-y$ just as you did, you should end with
$$2 u(y)u'(y) \tan (y) +1=0$$ which is separable. Let $z(y)=u^2(y)$ to get
$$z'(y)=-\frac {\cos(y)} {\sin(y)}$$ which is simple.